# Moving the first element to end in Numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a NumPy array, which I want to move the first element to the end. I know how to do it by converting to the list and do the insert operation but I want to avoid this and do it in a better and optimized way.

Suppose this is my array and I want to move 0 to the end:

```
x = [[ 0 388.13 19.346 412.38 39.594]
    [ 0 388.15 8.5168 416 38.972] 
    [ 0 223.14 156.21 317.91 193.46]]
```

I know I can do it in this way by converting to the list:

```py
X = X.tolist()
for ele in x:
    ele.insert(len(ele), ele.pop(0))
```

Is there any way to do it without converting it to a list (using numpy)? and also, the way I'm doing is not efficient, What is a possible way to make my code efficient in term of speed even by converting it to list?

Expected output:

```
x = [[388.13 19.346 412.38 39.594 0]
    [388.15 8.5168 416 38.972 0] 
    [223.14 156.21 317.91 193.46 0]]
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: You can store the first element in `temp` variable then do `np.delete()` then `np.append()` just remember to reshape your array.

Comment: One way or other you'll have to copy all values of the array to a new location, either in this array or a new one.  `numpy` does not a use a linked list storage where such a move would just require changing a few pointers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [`np.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) :`np.roll(x, -1, axis=1).tolist()`

Answer (score 6):

you could also try `np.hstack`:

```
np.hstack([x[:, 1:], x[:, :1]])
```

or even `np.concatenate`:

```
np.concatenate([x[:, 1:], x[:, :1]],  axis=1)
```

or even `np.c_`

```
np.c_[x[:, 1:], x[:, :1]]
```

all the above gives you:

```
array([[388.13  ,  19.346 , 412.38  ,  39.594 ,   0.    ],
       [388.15  ,   8.5168, 416.    ,  38.972 ,   0.    ],
       [223.14  , 156.21  , 317.91  , 193.46  ,   0.    ]])
```

Comment: You beat me to it!  Well played.